# Scaling range of values with negative numbers

Tags: math, scale

How can I scale a set of values to fit a new range if they include negative numbers?

For example, I have a set of numbers (-10, -9, 1, 4, 10) which have to scaled to a range [0 1], such that -10 maps to 0, and 10 maps to 1.

The regular method for an arbitrary number 'x' would be:
 (x - from_min) * (to_max - to_min) / (from_max - from_min) + to_min

but this does not work for negative numbers. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe id does; in your example,

```
from_min = -10,
from_max = 10,
to_max = 1,
to_min = 0.
```

This yields

```
to_max - to_min = 1,
from_max - from_min = 20;
```

So using the formula

```
x -> (x - from_min) * (to_max - to_min) / (from_max - from_min) + to_min
   = (x - from_min) * 1 / 20 + 0
   = (x - from_min) / 20
```

yields

```
-10 -> (-10 + 10) / 20 = 0 / 20,
-9 -> (-9 + 10) / 20 = 1 / 20,
1 -> (1 + 10) / 20 = 11 / 20,
4 -> (4 + 10) / 20 = 14 / 20,
10 -> (10 + 10) / 20 = 20 / 20,
```

so all the resulting values are nonnegative. Furthermore, the original minimum -10 maps to to_min = 0 and the original maximum 10 maps to to_max = 1. If this doesn't work in your implementation, check if you mixed up integral types and floating-point types.

Comment: Thanks! I believe I have made a mistake with the data types in the implementation. I will sort it out, thanks!

Comment: Thanks but if you want scale [0,1] then you wouldn't need to_min and to_max => minmax scale formula?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works fine for negative numbers.

You have:

- from_min = -10
- from_max = 10
- to_min = 0
- to_max = 1

Substituting these into your formula:

```
(x - (-10)) * (1 - 0) / (10 - (-10)) + 0
```

Which simplifies to:

```
(x + 10) / 20
```

Comment: Strange..... Guess I have messed up the implementation. I will double check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs it, here is solution proposed by @anonymous but in PHP:

```
function translations_Range2Range($x, $from_min, $from_max, $to_min, $to_max ) {
    if ($from_max == $from_min)
        return $to_max;
    return ($x - $from_min) * ($to_max - $to_min) / ($from_max - $from_min) + $to_min;
}
```

If there is a case where division by zero occurs, i.e. `($from_max == $from_min)` then the function returns `$to_max`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way to scale any value is with one formula:

output = (input - input_min) / (input_max - input_min) * (output_max - output_min) + output_min