# Linearly scaling a number in a certain range to a new range

Tags: javascript, function, scaling

I've made a scaling function that takes numbers in an interval `[oldMin,oldMax]` and scales them linearly to the range `[newMin,newMax]` . It does not seem to work when using negative values.

```
function linearScaling(oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax, oldValue){
        var newValue;
        if(oldMin !== oldMax && newMin !== newMax){
            newValue = parseFloat((((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin)) / (oldMax - oldMin))  + newMin);
            newValue = newValue.toFixed(2);
        }
        else{
            newValue = error;
        }
        return newValue;
}
```

This function seems to work when scaling a value from 0 -> 32761 to the range range 0 -> 10. However it does not seem to give the correct output when given a new negative range i.e. -10 -> 10

I have done my best to find an answer on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137348/scaling-range-of-values-with-negative-numbers). However the person who asked the question didn't mention what he ended up doing to fix  it. That question says it could have something to do with mixed up data types, but i converted everything to a float did I miss anything?

Comment: I wouldn't use `!=` on argument values. Do `!==`.

Comment: First remove the `parseFloat`. JavaScript only knows "Number"s, no "int" or "float".

Comment: range (0 -> 20) - 10 ?

Comment: Your function works for me: `linearScaling(0, 20, -10, 10, 5)` => `"-5.00"`

Comment: Maybe you should use more lines as well: `v -= oldMin; v /= oldMax; v *= newMax; v += newMin;`.

Comment: your function works for me with linearScaling(10, 20, -10, 10, 17); // returns 4.00 - what's the problem?

Comment: Please show _exactly_ how you called this function, and what the "erroneous" output was (a complete html snippet that we can load into a browser would be ideal). It doesn't seem anyone (me included) can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ kay: i need the parsefloat function because otherwise i can't set the precision with 'toFixed' and i really need a precision of 2.

Comment: @Floris : this is how i call the function:

'g1.refresh(linearScaling('0', '32761', '-10', '10', readData('IW0')));'

let me explain: g1 is a gage element and the refresh function is just to refresh it's value with what u enter between the brackets, the function readdata is a selfmade function that returns the value at adres 'IW0' and that value is between 0 and 32761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you showed how you call your function, I can reproduce your problem - namely that quoted numbers that should map to the negative domain don't.

It seems to be due to the fact that Javascript is very loose about the difference between a number and a string - and if it's not sure what to do about two numbers (because one of them appears to be a string), it assumes you want concatenation rather than addition. In other words - by passing the `newMin` value as `'-10'` rather than `-10` you confused JS.

As a simple example,

```
document.write('1' + '-2');
```

produces

```
1-2
```

However,

```
document.write(1*'1' + 1*'-2');
```

results in

```
-1
```

The expression you had included a "possible concatenation" where it added `oldMin`:

```
newValue = (((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin)) / (oldMax - oldMin))  + newMin;
```

With newMin set to '-10', you might get `newValue` to look like `6-10` instead of `-4`, to give an example. When you then did a `parseFloat`, Javascript would quietly work its way through the string up to the minus sign, and return `6` instead of evaluating the expression and coming up with `-4`.

To clear up the confusion, multiply each parameter by 1 to make it "a genuine number":

```
oldMin = 1*oldMin;
oldMax = 1*oldMax;
newMin = 1*newMin;
newMax = 1*newMax;
oldValue = 1*oldValue;
```

When you add these lines at the start of your function declaration, everything works smoothly - regardless of how you call the function. Or just call it with the `newMin` value not in quotes - it is the one causing the trouble in this particular instance.

```
  document.writeln('the new code called with parameter = 100:\n');
  document.writeln(linearScaling('0', '32761', '-10', '10', 100)+'<br>');
  document.writeln('the old code called with parameter = 100:\n');
  document.writeln(linearScalingOld('0.0', '32761.0', '-10.0', '10.0', '100.0')+'<br>');
  document.writeln('the old code called with unquoted parameters:\n');
  document.writeln(linearScalingOld(0.0, 32761.0, -10.0, 10.0, 100.0)+'<br>');
```

results in the following:

```
the new code called with parameter = 100: -9.94
the old code called with parameter = 100: 0.06
the old code called with unquoted parameters: -9.94
```

I hope this illustrates the cause of the problem, and the solution.

Comment: oh my god what a stupid little mistake, but thanks for helping me out and pointing out the problem so well, I totally understand now. 
I fixed my function by multiplying every variable with 1 so it doesn't matter if users call the function with quotes or without

Comment: no i don't :s u mean like click somewhere to confirm that my question is solved?